# Image quality after adding data-position="fixed" jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

My footer is a grey strip with 4 social media icon links. Looks great normally however since adding data-position="fixed" to the footer to ensure it sticks to to the bottom of the screen at all times, the image quality reduces.

See both images here, the top one being before adding the fixed code and the bottom being after.

I tried adding even larger HQ images after adding the fixed code but same problem. It's a weird one for me?

http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/image_links.png

Comment: Got nowhere with this yet, had some response on the JQM forum but they don't solve the issue. As son as I remove data-position="fixed" the images are perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by a very knowledgeable individual on the jQuery Mobile forum. I had got a bit confused and not stuck with the jQuery Mobile defaults footer/header structure so he corrected me.

Comment: It would be nicer if you put the link to the forum and to your question (on that forum) so that this answer can also be used by others in the SO community.